# Why is '0' not equal to an empty list?

Tags: javascript, equals

If 0 (as a digit) equals to 0 as a string, and 0 equals to an empty list, **why** 0 as a string is not equal to an empty list (from the moment that 0 as a digit equals to 0 as a string)?

```
> 0 == '0'
true
> 0 == []
true
> '0' == []
false
```

Comment: This has been asked numerous times and definitely qualifies as a pure duplicate.

Comment: @Hi-IloveSO Yes, I didn't see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand the results of your code, you need to understand how `==` equality operator works in the following cases:

- When both operands are of same type, return the result of strict equality comparison `===`
- If one operand is a number and other is a string, convert the string operand to a number
- If any or both operands are non-primitive, convert non-primitive operand to a primitive value

Keeping the above mentioned points in mind, lets see how each comparison is processed:

1. `0 == '0'`

   This evaluates to true because `'0'` is converted to a number and then strict equality comparison is performed since both operands have the same type after the conversion of `'0'` to a number.
2. `0 == []`

   returns true because when any operand of the `==` operator is non-primitive, it is converted in to a primitive value. Empty array when converted into a primitive value, results in an empty string. So after this conversion, you have `0 == ''`. Now one operand is a number and other is a string. Empty string is then converted to a number which results in `0` leading to the comparison of `0 == 0` which evaluated to true.
3. `'0' == []`

   this returns false because empty array is converted to a primitive value which is an empty string. When `[]` is converted to an empty string, types of both operands (`'0' == ''`) are same, so strict equality comparison is done which returns false.

For details, see [Ecmascript Spec: 7.2.15: Abstract Equality Comparison](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, double equals does not mean strictly equal to, whereas tripple equals `===` does. In the former cases a conversion is made as a result of the types involved, whereas no such available conversion (which results in semi-equality) exists in the latter case.

Answer (score 0):

. You have 3 cases.

1. when you write '0' == 0 , the Value of '0' in utf-8 is 0 hence
   false ==false is true
2. String is basically a list in python when  you write '0' you are basically making a list with an element '
   '0' ie '0' ==['0'] and not [ ] hence true==false is false
3. while when you write 0==[ ] every value with  0 is false and the empty list returns the Boolean value of number of elements in the list which is False for 0 hence false ==false is true

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript is designed that way.
In `0 == '0'`
`==` converts '0' to 0 because the right operand is a number
So what happens is it checks 0 == 0 which is true.
Tips use `===` called strick equality comparison to check, which will treat `0` as a number and `'0'` as a string.

`0 == []`
In Javascript empty array is treated as a falsy, while 0 is always false and 1 truth.

So == compares `false == false` which is true. Once again use strict equity sign `===`

`'0' == []`

Here since [] is not a number Javascript won't care to convert '0' to 0 which means the comparison is comparing string and array which will won't be true.

Comment: empty array is not a falsy value in js